# jQuery slide toggle corresponding service item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Working on a jQuery slide toggle where upon click of an item in a ul toggle down the corresponding item in another ul. I'm having trouble getting the click to be linked to the id and toggling the correct ul item.

jQuery is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//on click of subservices list item toggle down the corresponding subservices item

$(".subServices").find("li").hide().end() // Hide all other ULs
.click(function(e) {
    if (this == e.target) {  // if the handler element is where the event originated
        $(this).children('ul.subServicesList.subServiceItem').slideToggle('fast');
    }
});
});
```

Can anyone help :)

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/zc60o0au/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, ID of an element must be unique so you can't use same ID for `subServices` and `SubServicesList`. In the below solution we uses a `data-target` attribute for `subServices`.

Also you need to register the handler to `.SubServicesList a` element, not the `SubServicesList`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //on click of subservices list item toggle down the corresponding subservices item

  $(".subServices > li").hide().end() // Hide all other ULs
  $('.SubServicesList a').click(function(e) {
    $('#' + $(this).data('target')).slideToggle()
  });
});
```

```css
.SubServicesList {
  display: block;
  width: 55%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.SubServicesList li {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 26px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.SubServicesList li a:hover {
  color: #333333;
}
.subServices {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.subServices li.subServiceItem {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: auto;
  clear: both;
}
.subServices li.subServiceItem .image {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.subServices li.subServiceItem .image {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
/*.subServices li.subServiceItem { display:none; } */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="SubServicesList">
  <li><a data-target="1">Name 1</a></li>
  <li><a data-target="2">Name 2</a></li>
  <li><a data-target="3">Name 3</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="subServices">
  <li class="subServiceItem" id="1">
    1 hwiufhwriufhiurhfiureh
  </li>
  <li class="subServiceItem" id="2">
    2 hwiufhwriufhiurhfiureh
  </li>
  <li class="subServiceItem" id="3">
    3 hwiufhwriufhiurhfiureh
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it

```
$(".SubServicesList > li > a").click(function () {
    $(".subServices>li").hide();
    $(".subServices").find("li[id='" + $(this).attr('id') + "']").slideToggle(true);
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/zc60o0au/3/)